# Filtering rows in joined query

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I don't manage to filter a query's results. Here it is the query I'm executing:

```sql
SELECT 
ORE.ID AS OR_ID, 
ORE.INIT_VERSION AS OR_INIT_VERSION,
ORE.INSERT_DATE AS OR_INSERT_DATE, 
ORE.INIT_DATE AS OR_INIT_DATE,
ORE.END_DATE AS OR_END_DATE, 
ORE.STATE AS OR_STATE,
ORE.ACTION_NAME AS OR_ACTION_NAME,
ORH.STATE_ID AS ORH_STATE_ID,
ORH.INSERT_DATE AS ORH_INSERT_DATE,
CS.STATE AS CS_STATE

FROM ORDER_REQUEST ORE 
INNER JOIN ORDER_REQUEST_HISTORY ORH ON ORH.ORDER_REQUEST_ID = ORE.ID AND ORH.COMPONENT_ID = ORE.ARCH_ID
INNER JOIN COMPONENT_STATE CS ON CS.ID = ORH.STATE_ID
WHERE ORE.ARCH_ID = 219934
AND CS.STATE IN ('CREAZIONE', 'ANNULLATO', 'REVISIONE PIANIFICATA', 'APPROVAZIONE PIANIFICATA', 'APPROVAZIONE RIFIUTATA', 'COMPLETATO', 'COMPLETATA')
```

which returns the following result:

```
OR_ID   OR_STATE    OR_INIT_DATE    OR_ACTION_NAME  ORH_STATE_ID    OR_END_DATE     CS_STATE    ORH_INSERT_DATE     OR_INSERT_DATE          OR_INIT_VERSION
8821    COMPLETATA  2014-04-07      ATT             111             2014-06-03      COMPLETATA  15-05-2014 12:48:32 07-04-2014 16:49:42     1
12266   ACQUISITO   2014-06-03      VAR             10018           NULL            CREAZIONE   30-06-2014 18:59:40 03-06-2014 15:53:51     2
12266   ACQUISITO   2014-06-03      VAR             10018           NULL            CREAZIONE   01-07-2014 12:56:20 03-06-2014 15:53:51     2
```

I'd like to filter in such a way that for each OR_ID I get only the row with the maximum ORH_INSERT_DATE, i.e. the first and third row of the result.
I tried different aproaches, but none seems to work.
Particularly I've tried to complicate the JOIN:

```sql
    INNER JOIN ORDER_REQUEST_HISTORY ORH ON ORH.ORDER_REQUEST_ID = ORE.ID AND ORH.COMPONENT_ID = ORE.ARCH_ID AND ORH.INSERT_DATE = (SELECT INSERT_DATE FROM ORDER_REQUEST_HISTORY ORH2 WHERE ORH2.ORDER_REQUEST_ID = ORE.ID)
```

but it returns only the first row of the results above. I also tried to complicate the WHERE clause the same way, but it still returns me only the first row of the result set above.

Does anybody have any idea about what is the right clause to add? Or should I pass to make subsequent queries and solve it the good ol hard way?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Gianluca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WITH` clause and `ROW_NUMBER` function to do this, like so:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT 
 ORE.ID AS OR_ID, 
 ORE.INIT_VERSION AS OR_INIT_VERSION,
 ORE.INSERT_DATE AS OR_INSERT_DATE, 
 ORE.INIT_DATE AS OR_INIT_DATE,
 ORE.END_DATE AS OR_END_DATE, 
 ORE.STATE AS OR_STATE,
 ORE.ACTION_NAME AS OR_ACTION_NAME,
 ORH.STATE_ID AS ORH_STATE_ID,
 ORH.INSERT_DATE AS ORH_INSERT_DATE,
 CS.STATE AS CS_STATE,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ORE.ID ORDER BY ORH.INSERT_DATE DESC) AS RN
 FROM ORDER_REQUEST ORE 
 INNER JOIN ORDER_REQUEST_HISTORY ORH ON ORH.ORDER_REQUEST_ID = ORE.ID AND      ORH.COMPONENT_ID = ORE.ARCH_ID
 INNER JOIN COMPONENT_STATE CS ON CS.ID = ORH.STATE_ID
 WHERE ORE.ARCH_ID = 219934
 AND CS.STATE IN ('CREAZIONE', 'ANNULLATO', 'REVISIONE PIANIFICATA', 'APPROVAZIONE PIANIFICATA', 'APPROVAZIONE RIFIUTATA', 'COMPLETATO', 'COMPLETATA')
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

The idea is to partition based on the `OR_ID` and find the row with maximum value for `ORH_INSERT_DATE`. You can also select only specific columns by substituting `*` with the desired columns.

Comment: You are a f***ing genious!

Comment: Actually I am sure there is a better way to do this without a CTE but I am away from my dev box so I can't test and post that.

Comment: Well, I've been actually wasting an entire morning to make that query work trying a lot of things: complicating the join, complicating the where, using subselectes, aso. I got your answer working for me, which is nice. Thanks again